# Resigning before a new work permit is issued

Tags: hiring-process, relocation, visa

Recently, I received an offer from a company (let's call it company A) which hires IT specialists to work in Switzerland. On my end, I currently hold a non-EU citizenship and I'm working in the Netherlands with a valid residence permit tied to my employer. The notice period of my current employer (let's call it company B) is 3 months. If I quit without anything lined up, I have a short period of time to find a new job.

I still did not sign the offer from company A, as I did not see any info about how we will handle potentially delayed visa and work-permit. Therefore, I would like to ask for advice on the following options that I think I have:

Option 1: Ask company A to include a clause in the contract that would allow me to start working from the Netherlands, in case the work-permit / visa is delayed. I could easily transfer my work permit to the new employer. In the meanwhile, give company B the leaving notice of 3 months. When the work-permit arrives, I move to Switzerland and start working.

Option 2: Do not give leaving notice to company B until the work-permit is issued, which might take more time (3-6 months), or even worse, it might be a rejected. In this case, the start time for company A will be delayed by at least 3 months (3 months best case for visa + 3 months leaving notice).

Is one of the two options better? Ideally, option 1 would be perfect, given company A agrees. Or is there another way to handle a situation such as this?

Comment: I like both options you've outlined. They're both very well thought out. But frankly, we can't make that decision for you. There is a lot that can go wrong whichever option you take (or not take).

Comment: Option 1 maximizes career progression but carries a greater risk to job security. Option 2 maximizes job security at the expense of potential missed opportunity to progress your career. You need to decide which is more important to you, job security or career progression.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments. @numenor why do you feel that option 1 is more risky for job security? Given I start with the new job on the exact start date, but from the Netherlands?

Comment: @CClarke that is because asking for non-standard change to contracts is potentially risky. In my experience (I've signed 20+ contracts), clients are generally closed to this, simply for the reason that any change to a contract's wording involves another legal review round trip. I would consider rather than request a contractual change, instead try to secure a written agreement that they are accepting of you starting your new role in a remote capacity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @numenor! Highly appreciated.

Comment: @CClarke "I could easily transfer my work permit to the new employer." Perhaps you can clarify a bit here: how could a Switzerland-based company support a visa for you in the Netherlands? Do you have the legal ability to remain in the Netherlands beyond your existing work-related visa? Even if you do (e.g. through converting to anther residency status), have you looked into the tax implications of being a tax resident of the Netherlands but earning money in Switzerland?

Comment: As commenters have mentioned already both options have a trade-off. I always dealt with such situations in following manner: When you are still young, no family to take care off and no monthly mortage payments, then I'd go with the more risky option (good carrer-growth, low job-sec). If you have serious monthly financial commitments to take care of and other ppl such as family depend on a secure income, then I'd rather choose the safer options and skip on the carrer growth. Ideally you would find both in an oportunity, but that's quite rare..

Comment: Thank you @iLuvLogix and the rest for the comments, they've been of great help to a fellow stranger :-)

Comment: Have you checked the Canton where you expect to work? A work permit is not a residence permit.

Comment: "as I did not see any info about how we will handle potentially delayed visa and work-permit" how about you just ask your prospect employer how they plan to handle the situation? If it's a big enough company, you probably aren't the first non -EU citizen they hire. And even if you are, if they are really interested in hiring you (as they seem to be), they will find a solution (if they don't have a procedure already in place).

Comment: I think this question should be moved to the Expatriates / immigration stack exchange

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't fit here but might fit on expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is company A, a startup?

Answer (score 2):

Don't decide this in a vacuum.  Have a conversation with company A.  Tell them you're excited about the opportunity and eager to start, but you have the constraints that you need to give 3 months notice at your current job and you need the valid visa for Switzerland.

In the companies I've worked for, a predictable start date (ie, Option 1) for onboarding a new employee would be preferable from a team perspective, but whether or not the company can employ you legally from the Netherlands is a whole bunch of corporate paperwork and legal stuff that only they can know.  You need to see if that's even an option.

As you say - if option 1 can't work, it's pretty much option 2.  In that one, the company's immigration folks may also have some good ideas - for example, there may a point where they know the visa is close enough to guaranteed, and you can give notice then, condensing the time just a bit.

But you really need a conversation with them.  The options are very country and company specific.  Most companies hiring in this space are aware of the limits, though, and should be ready for this one - when I hired folks in Poland, it was very similar, and we just had to roll with the limitations of both the former employment country and the new country's immigration laws.